# Google Apps script : Move to a particular cell when sheet is active

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with multiple sheets. One of the sheets is in a calendar format, which means there are specific cells with a particular date of the year. The sheet is long, so when I have to search for the cell with a particular date, I have to scroll a bit. I want to automate this using google apps script. So in a nutshell, when I move to that sheet, the active cell should be a particular cell identified with current date. I know how to identify the cell but how to set my cursor to that cell every time the sheet is active. Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe share a sample of your sheet and a piece of code of what have you done so far?

Comment: @Raserhin, thanks for your response. I don't think spreadsheet / code is needed. All I need here is to know how to scroll directly to particular cell when a sheet is active

Comment: Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help please add a brief descritption of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: ``range.activate()``